# How can I enable a specific supported link to an app in Android via adb?

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, automated-tests, adb

I am performing some tests for an application where I need to open some link in a browser and interact with some buttons to then open the app.

So, I am not using deeplinks, instead, set the app as default to open supported links using `adb shell pm set-app-links-allowed  --user 0 --package app.package.name true`.
The problem is that this enables the app to open supported links, but since all of the links are not enabled by default, I have to enable them via adb since interacting with UI is not a good approach because the test is going to be executed in different devices.

Is there a way to enable de supported links after setting the app as default, so then the app can be opened from links in the browser like "open in app"?